# jQuery populated dropdown not getting value in ASP .net backend

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

My front-end code:

```
            <asp:DropDownList ID="txtBoxBankCountry"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="--Select Country--"></asp:ListItem>               
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

By ajax I am appending the countries in it:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Registration.aspx/getCountryData",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data.d);
                var countries = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
                var option = "<option value='-1'>--Select Country--</option>";
                for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
                    option += "<option value='" + countries[i].location_id + "'>" + countries[i].name + "</option>";
                }

                $('#txtBoxBankCountry').html(option);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
```

Now when in the back-end I am fetching the data its getting the value "--Select Country--" only.

I read on stackoverflow and got to know that when we use ajax to append the data in drop down, backend doesn't know about it. It can only reach to **asp:ListItems**.

How can I fix this and get correct selected text. I can't use postback as its refreshing the page and I don't want that.

My backend code:

```
string bankCountry = txtBoxBankCountry.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're looking for. The only thing looking like a question is _"How can I handle this situation"_. Do you want to know how to post the data, without "postback", or do you have any problems with your current code?

Comment: @Mackan Its not getting the correct selected value in aspx.cs code. Its only fetching "--Select Country--" every time. I want the selected text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for you to be populating your dropdown from a jQuery AJAX call, you're just causing yourself headaches in the world of Web Forms.

To achieve this, you're best off using good ol' fashion Microsoft Ajax. Instead, put your html inside an `UpdatePanel` then populating the dropdown list on the server, then the dropdown will be re-populated automatically.

There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) on using the `UpdatePanel`.